# Video compression usging FFmpeg not working on android 10

Tags: android, compression, video-compression

I am trying to compress the videos in android programmatically using this library 
https://github.com/jczmdeveloper/XCVideoCompressor
It's working fine till android 9, but on android 10 it's giving error

Please help me with video compression in android

Answer (score 0):

Android Api 29 and above Removed execute permission for app home directory. Apps that target Android 10 cannot invoke exec() on files within the app's home directory

[See on this link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission)

Unfortunately I did not find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

```
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.2.2.LTS'
```

and this command

```
String cmd = "-y -i " + oldPath + " -c:a copy -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast " + newFile.getPath();
```